# dojo stackedColumnsPlot chart customization

Tags: javascript, charts, dojo, customization

```
JSon Data: 
{
    "identifier": "instance_name",
    "items": [
        {
            "version_name": "16.11.0.0-b354",
            "instance_name": "osvc_okcsqb990",
            "site_capacity": 2,
            "connected_sites": 0,
            "sites_overload_factor": 0
        },
        {
            "version_name": "16.5.4.2-b2",
            "instance_name": "osvc_okcsqb1400",
            "site_capacity": 2,
            "connected_sites": 1,
            "sites_overload_factor": 0.5
        },
        {
            "version_name": "17.11.0.0-b269",
            "instance_name": "seo_ora18i",
            "site_capacity": 0,
            "connected_sites": 1,
            "sites_overload_factor": 1
        },
        {
            "version_name": "17.11.0.0-b332",
            "instance_name": "osvc_okcsqb1402",
            "site_capacity": 4,
            "connected_sites": 4,
            "sites_overload_factor": 1
        },
        {
            "version_name": "17.11.0.0-b332",
            "instance_name": "osvc_okcsqb1430",
            "site_capacity": 1,
            "connected_sites": 0,
            "sites_overload_factor": 0
        },
        {
            "version_name": "17.11.0.0-b372",
            "instance_name": "fusion_okcsqb517",
            "site_capacity": 8,
            "connected_sites": 6,
            "sites_overload_factor": 0.75
        },
        {
            "version_name": "17.11.0.0-b380",
            "instance_name": "E2E_W05_1711GA_18800_qb1422",
            "site_capacity": 8,
            "connected_sites": 7,
            "sites_overload_factor": 0.875
        },
        {
            "version_name": "17.11.0.0-b380",
            "instance_name": "fusion_okcsqb1141",
            "site_capacity": 8,
            "connected_sites": 7,
            "sites_overload_factor": 0.875
        },
        {
            "version_name": "17.11.0.0-b380",
            "instance_name": "fusion_okcsqb1277",
            "site_capacity": 4,
            "connected_sites": 5,
            "sites_overload_factor": 1.25
        },
        {
            "version_name": "17.11.0.0-b380",
            "instance_name": "fusion_okcsqb1433",
            "site_capacity": 2,
            "connected_sites": 3,
            "sites_overload_factor": 1.5
        },
        {
            "version_name": "17.11.0.0-b380",
            "instance_name": "osvc_okcsqb1386",
            "site_capacity": 8,
            "connected_sites": 8,
            "sites_overload_factor": 1
        },
        {
            "version_name": "17.11.0.0-b52-int",
            "instance_name": "fusion_okcsqb1348",
            "site_capacity": 8,
            "connected_sites": 1,
            "sites_overload_factor": 0.125
        },
        {
            "version_name": "17.2.4.0-b3",
            "instance_name": "osvc_okcsqb1432",
            "site_capacity": 1,
            "connected_sites": 3,
            "sites_overload_factor": 3
        },
        {
            "version_name": "17.2.5.0-b67",
            "instance_name": "osvc_okcsqb1440",
            "site_capacity": 8,
            "connected_sites": 10,
            "sites_overload_factor": 1.25
        },
        {
            "version_name": "17.5.1.0-b63",
            "instance_name": "osvc_okcsqb1229",
            "site_capacity": 4,
            "connected_sites": 10,
            "sites_overload_factor": 2.5
        },
        {
            "version_name": "17.5.3.0-b9",
            "instance_name": "okcsdata175",
            "site_capacity": 8,
            "connected_sites": 18,
            "sites_overload_factor": 2.25
        },
        {
            "version_name": "17.5.4.0-b11",
            "instance_name": "175xiao",
            "site_capacity": 8,
            "connected_sites": 0,
            "sites_overload_factor": 0
        },
        {
            "version_name": "17.5.5.0-b4",
            "instance_name": "osvc_okcsqb1428",
            "site_capacity": 8,
            "connected_sites": 0,
            "sites_overload_factor": 0
        },
        {
            "version_name": "17.5.5.0-b4",
            "instance_name": "osvc_okcsqb1431",
            "site_capacity": 1,
            "connected_sites": 2,
            "sites_overload_factor": 2
        },
        {
            "version_name": "17.8.0.0-b238",
            "instance_name": "Fusion_SD",
            "site_capacity": 2,
            "connected_sites": 2,
            "sites_overload_factor": 1
        },
        {
            "version_name": "17.8.0.0-b343",
            "instance_name": "osvc_okcsqb1274",
            "site_capacity": 1,
            "connected_sites": 0,
            "sites_overload_factor": 0
        },
        {
            "version_name": "17.8.0.0-b352",
            "instance_name": "osvc_okcsqb1396",
            "site_capacity": 1,
            "connected_sites": 1,
            "sites_overload_factor": 1
        },
        {
            "version_name": "17.8.2.0-b1schemaTest",
            "instance_name": "SchemaProv",
            "site_capacity": 1,
            "connected_sites": 1,
            "sites_overload_factor": 1
        },
        {
            "version_name": "17.8.2.0-b21",
            "instance_name": "osvc_okcsqb1373",
            "site_capacity": 8,
            "connected_sites": 4,
            "sites_overload_factor": 0.5
        },
        {
            "version_name": "17.8.2.0-b6",
            "instance_name": "fusion_okcsqb1106",
            "site_capacity": 8,
            "connected_sites": 6,
            "sites_overload_factor": 0.75
        },
        {
            "version_name": "17.8.2.0-b6",
            "instance_name": "fusion_okcsqb1161",
            "site_capacity": 8,
            "connected_sites": 4,
            "sites_overload_factor": 0.5
        },
        {
            "version_name": "17.8.2.0-b6",
            "instance_name": "fusion_okcsqb1265",
            "site_capacity": 8,
            "connected_sites": 8,
            "sites_overload_factor": 1
        },
        {
            "version_name": "17.8.2.0-b6",
            "instance_name": "fusion_okcsqb1275",
            "site_capacity": 8,
            "connected_sites": 7,
            "sites_overload_factor": 0.875
        },
        {
            "version_name": "17.8.2.0-b6",
            "instance_name": "fusion_okcsqb1367",
            "site_capacity": 1,
            "connected_sites": 3,
            "sites_overload_factor": 3
        },
        {
            "version_name": "17.8.2.0-b6",
            "instance_name": "fusion_okcsqb1415",
            "site_capacity": 4,
            "connected_sites": 3,
            "sites_overload_factor": 0.75
        },
        {
            "version_name": "17.8.2.0-b6",
            "instance_name": "fusion_okcsqb518",
            "site_capacity": 4,
            "connected_sites": 6,
            "sites_overload_factor": 1.5
        },
        {
            "version_name": "17.8.2.0-b6",
            "instance_name": "fusion_okcsqb942",
            "site_capacity": 2,
            "connected_sites": 6,
            "sites_overload_factor": 3
        },
        {
            "version_name": "17.8.3.0-b1",
            "instance_name": "E2E_W01_178_22300_qb1441",
            "site_capacity": 8,
            "connected_sites": 0,
            "sites_overload_factor": 0
        },
        {
            "version_name": "17.8.3.0-b1",
            "instance_name": "osvc_okcsqb1436",
            "site_capacity": 8,
            "connected_sites": 10,
            "sites_overload_factor": 1.25
        },
        {
            "version_name": "18.2.0.0-b100",
            "instance_name": "osvc_okcsqb1390",
            "site_capacity": 8,
            "connected_sites": 0,
            "sites_overload_factor": 0
        },
        {
            "version_name": "18.2.0.0-b112",
            "instance_name": "osvc_okcsqb1423",
            "site_capacity": 8,
            "connected_sites": 1,
            "sites_overload_factor": 0.125
        },
        {
            "version_name": "18.2.0.0-b130-int",
            "instance_name": "idc_search_dev_182_instance",
            "site_capacity": 8,
            "connected_sites": 16,
            "sites_overload_factor": 2
        },
        {
            "version_name": "18.2.0.0-b143-int",
            "instance_name": "osvc_okcsqb1426",
            "site_capacity": 8,
            "connected_sites": 9,
            "sites_overload_factor": 1.125
        },
        {
            "version_name": "18.2.0.0-b143-int",
            "instance_name": "osvc_okcsqb1438",
            "site_capacity": 8,
            "connected_sites": 2,
            "sites_overload_factor": 0.25
        },
        {
            "version_name": "18.2.0.0-b3CleanClone",
            "instance_name": "cleanclone182",
            "site_capacity": 8,
            "connected_sites": 4,
            "sites_overload_factor": 0.5
        }
    ]
}
```

```js
require([
    "dojo/dom",
    "dojo/ready",
    "dojo/dom-construct",
    "dojo/request",
    "dojo/json",
    "dojo/data/ItemFileReadStore",
    "dojo/store/Memory",
    "dojo/data/ObjectStore",
    "dojox/charting/plot2d/StackedColumns",
    "dojox/charting/Chart",
    "dojox/charting/axis2d/Default",
    "dojox/charting/Chart2D",
    "dojox/charting/action2d/Highlight",
    "dojox/charting/action2d/Tooltip",
    "dojox/charting/themes/MiamiNice",
    "dojox/charting/widget/Legend",
    "dojox/charting/action2d/Magnify",
    "dojox/charting/themes/Claro",
    "dojox/charting/themes/PlotKit/green"
  ],
  function(dom, ready, domConstruct,
    request, JSON, item_file_store, Memory, ObjectStore,
    StackedColumns, Chart, Default, Chart2D, Highlight,
    Tooltip, MiamiNice, Legend, Magnify, claroTheme, greenTheme) {
    ready(function() {
      request.get("data/qb/instances_in_versions.json", {
        handleAs: "json"
      }).then(function(data) {
        objectItemStore = new ObjectStore({
          objectStore: new Memory({
            data: data.items
          })
        });
        array_okcs_instance_counts = [];
        array_fusion_instance_counts = [];
        array_x_axis_label_names = [];

        objectItemStore.fetch({
          query: {
            version_name: "*"
          },
          sort: [{
            attribute: 'version_name',
            descending: true
          }],
          onItem: function(item, request) {
            var okcs_instance_count = objectItemStore.getValue(item, "OSVC_Instance_Count");
            var fusion_instance_count = objectItemStore.getValue(item, "Fusion_Instance_Count");
            if (okcs_instance_count === 0 && fusion_instance_count === 0) {
              // do nothing
            } else {
              array_okcs_instance_counts.push(okcs_instance_count);
              array_fusion_instance_counts.push(fusion_instance_count);
              var label = objectItemStore.getValue(item, "version_name");
              var obj = {};
              obj.value = array_okcs_instance_counts.length;
              obj.text = label;
              array_x_axis_label_names.push(obj);
            }
          }
        });

        var obj1 = {};
        obj1.value = array_okcs_instance_counts.length + 1;
        obj1.text = "";
        array_okcs_instance_counts.push(0);
        array_fusion_instance_counts.push(0);
        array_x_axis_label_names.push(obj1);

        // identify the element in which you want to place the chart
        var chartTitle = "Products Details"
        var div_for_chart = document.getElementById('widget11_instances_in_versions_chart');
        // create chart object in the specified html element object
        var instances_in_versions_chart = new Chart2D(div_for_chart, {
          title: chartTitle,
          titlePos: "top",
          titleGap: 25,
          titleFont: "normal normal normal 15pt Arial",
          titleFontColor: "blue"
        })

        instances_in_versions_chart.addPlot("stackedColumnsPlot", {
          type: StackedColumns,
          lines: true,
          areas: true,
          gap: 5,
          markers: true,
          tension: "S"
        });

        instances_in_versions_chart.addAxis("x", {
          dropLabels: false,
          includeZero: true,
          microTicks: false,
          majorLabel: false,
          majorTicks: true,
          majorTickStep: 1,
          minorLabel: true,
          minorTicks: false,
          rotation: -30,
          fixLower: "major",
          fixUpper: "major",
          font: "normal normal bold",
          fontColor: "black",
          max: array_fusion_instance_counts.length,
          labels: array_x_axis_label_names
        });


        instances_in_versions_chart.addAxis("y", {
          vertical: true,
          fixLower: "major",
          fixUpper: "major",
          majorTickStep: 1,
          includezero: false,
          min: 0,
          labelFunc: function(text, value, precision) {
            var n = Number(text);
            return n.toFixed(0);
          }
        });

        instances_in_versions_chart.addSeries("OKCS Instances", array_okcs_instance_counts, {
          plot: "stackedColumnsPlot",
          stroke: {
            color: "blue"
          },
          fill: "blue"
        });

        instances_in_versions_chart.addSeries("Fusion Instances", array_fusion_instance_counts, {
          plot: "stackedColumnsPlot",
          stroke: {
            color: "green"
          },
          fill: "green"
        });

        //                    new Magnify(instances_in_versions_chart, "stackedColumnsPlot", {
        //                        scale: 1.1
        //                    });
        new Highlight(instances_in_versions_chart, "stackedColumnsPlot");
        new Tooltip(instances_in_versions_chart, "stackedColumnsPlot");
        instances_in_versions_chart.setTheme(claroTheme);
        instances_in_versions_chart.resize(490, 380);
        instances_in_versions_chart.render();
      });
    });

  });
```

```html
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="dijit/themes/claro/claro.css" media="screen" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css" />
    <!-- load Dojo -->
    <script src="dojo/dojo.js" data-dojo-config="async: true"></script>
</head>

<table id="row-three-table" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5" style="border:1px solid #fff;" width="960px">
  <tr style="height:400px;">
    <td style="width: 500px;border:1px solid #fff; border-width:1px 1px 0 0;">
      <div id="cell-31" class="scrollable_cell">
        <div id="widget31">31</div>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td style="width: 200px;border:1px solid #ccc; border-width:1px 1px 0 0;">
      <div id="cell-32" class="scrollable_cell">
        <div id="widget32">33</div>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td style="width: 200px;border:1px solid #ccc; border-width:1px 1px 0 0;">
      <div id="cell-33" class="scrollable_cell">
        <div id="widget33">33</div>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

[Link to the sample stackedColumnsPlot chart here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qp8ma.jpg)

1. I see there is no 1 and 29 present, I dont want to see this on
   x-axis
2. There is space between y-axis and first plot, I want to remove that
   space.
3. There is space after last plot, I want to remove that space.
4. Lastly, there is huge space between labels on y-axis and start of
   chart, I want to minimize that too.

Comment: data is a json file: